# Changing the bitmap image of an ImageView in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

So I have an ArrayList of Bitmap Images in my android app, and when I try to update the source of the image, nothing happens.  The ImageView displays the first Bitmap Image without a problem in my app, but when I try to update the ImageView with a new Bitmap image, nothing changes, and I receive no errors and my app does not crash. Here is the code:

```
public void setFirstImage() {

    imagePreview.setImageBitmap(framesArray.get(0));

}

public void setLastImage() {
    Log.e("Image to display", "The image is " + framesArray.get(5));
    // Yes, this image does exist
    imagePreview.invalidate();
    imagePreview.setImageBitmap(framesArray.get(5));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `invalidate()` after changing the bitmap, not before.

Comment: Nope, this did not work.  I think I need to solve my solution in another manner anyways

Comment: Scratch that, I still need this solution.

Comment: Figured it out.  It had nothing to do with setting the ImageView, but I was gathering my images from a video with the method `dataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(time)` and was passing in a value for milliseconds, but it actually requires microseconds.

Comment: Glad you found the issue.